# Using the new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, how to align outgoing and incoming texts like whatsapp or facebook messenger, in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

P.S. EDIT Is it even possible to align CardView programatically?

I found some solutions for the old FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, but they are not working. Any suggestions?

I used this code in java, from an old SO post but it has no affect

```
if (model.getReceiver() != "ADMIN")
                    holder.msgLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.START);
                else
                    holder.msgLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.END);
```

This is the layout of the chat activity, with only a RecyclerView 
and the bottom layout for writing and sending text and image.

activity_chat.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ChatActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view2"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/photoPickerButton"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/send_button_label"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is layout I use for each entry in the RecyclerView. 
It has a CardView, containing a LinearLayout which has some TextViews. I that where the problem could be? Should I use some Linear or Relative Layout in he root?

chat_message_entry_layout.xml

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/msgCardView"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/msgLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/msg"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:backgroundTint="#0e0d0e"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but `setGravity` is not what you're looking for.

You should be getting the `LayoutParams` of your `LinearLayout` and setting proper gravity on those.

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = 
                  (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) msgLinearLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
msgLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Notice that the `LayoutParams` type is not `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` but `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`. This is because `getLayoutParams` relates to the enclosing layout of the `msgLinearLayout` (which is the `CardView`). `CardView` is extending `FrameLayout`, hence the type of `params`.

---

If this doesn't help you, I will need some more data about your case. Maybe some illustrations of the desired effect? and what it looks like right now

Comment: hi, thanks. I was sure this would be it. This approach rectified a lot of my mistakes.
but there is no affect here. 
main points of what I am doing are -
1. creating a chat app (like whatsapp)
2. Loading the messages from firebase
3. setting them with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter (new model has changed)
4. need them to align left or right of screen depending on the receiver (if receiver is admin, align right. else align left)

earlier this snippet was used in onPopulateVIew & it appears it worked for people. That was before my time. 
even tried changing to FrameLayout.

any suggestions?

Comment: hey it found the mistake.
Your method works.
I was using condition 
    if(model.getReceiver != "ADMIN"), to decide the alignment
which was wrong.
    if(!model.getReceiver.equals("ADMIN")) was the correct way.
Therefore the condition wasn't factoring in the alignment.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CForge glad you could figure this out before I could even resond :D Happy to help!

Comment: you are a god-sent